# displaying multiple networkx plots in four grid and export to pdf

Tags: matplotlib, graph, networkx

I just split a network graph into four levels and I would like to display all four plots in four grid plots.

The structure of my code seems something below:

```
graph1=nx.cycle_graph(2)
graph2=nx.cycle_graph(3)
graph3=nx.cycle_graph(4)
graph4=nx.cycle_graph(5)

def draw_graph (graph, level):
    if (level ==1):
       graph=nx.cycle_graph(2)

    if (level ==2):
       graph=nx.cycle_graph(3)

    if (level ==3):
       graph=nx.cycle_graph(4)

    if (level ==4):
       graph=nx.cycle_graph(5)

    pos = nx.circular_layout(graph)


    nx.draw(graph,  pos = pos, node_color ='lightgreen', node_size = 1500 )

    nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos =pos,  font_size=13,
                            font_color = 'white', font_family='sans-serif') 

    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [11,11]
    plt.savefig("Four grid plot.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.axis('off')    
    plt.show()
```

I would like to display all levels in four grid plot something below and export it to pdf:

```
         |
level 1  | level 2
         | 
---------|-----------
         |
level 3  |  level 4
         |
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: You can pass in an axis instance into the `networkx` drawing commands. So you can setup a 2x2 grid of axes (`fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)`) and then pass in the individual axis instances (`nx.draw(graph, pos=pos, ..., ax=axes[0,0]`).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I am getting only one result and two empty subplots. Could you make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Per comment above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

graphs = [nx.cycle_graph(ii) for ii in range(2, 6)]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
for graph, ax in zip(graphs, axes.ravel()):
    nx.draw(graph, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In this case, it works perfectly. How about in my example above? Because I have four levels and accessing them via ```if``` condition as you see it. How can I access every graph that created at every level?

Comment: Your code snippet is not complete enough to run it, so I can't help you with that. Also, your doing weird stuff in that function, for example overwriting your `graph` function argument, so there might be other sources of error in there that have nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: Indeed. What if if I have these four graphs: 
```
graph1=nx.cycle_graph(2)
graph2=nx.cycle_graph(3)
graph3=nx.cycle_graph(4)
graph4=nx.cycle_graph(5)
```

Is that possible to work with your solution?

Comment: That is what my solution produces. Cycle graphs with nodes 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: I mean by considering their graph names like graph1, graph2, graph3, and graph4 separately not in one name like ``` graphs ```. If there is a way to do that?

Comment: Sure. You would not use a for loop but make the four calls explicitly. `nx.draw(graph1, ax=axes[0,0]; nx.draw(graph2, ax=axes[0,1])`, etc.